# How to implement shapper:shap for whole dataset?

Tags: r, random-forest, shap

I have created a Random Forest model using the randomForest package

`model_rf <- randomForest(y~ . , data = data_train,ntree=1000, keep.forest=TRUE,importance=TRUE)`

To calculate Shapley values for the different features based on this RF model, I first create an "explainer object" and then use the "shapper" package

`exp_rf <- DALEX::explain(model_rf, data = data_test[,-1], y = data_test[,1])`

`ive_rf <- shap(exp_rf, new_observation = data_test[1,-1])`

To my knowledge, I can only apply the "shap" function to one observation (the "new_observation").

But I am looking for a way to calculate the shapley values for all of my respondents in my datafile.
I know this is possible in the "SHAP" package in Python; but is it also possible with the "shapper" package in R?

At the moment, I created a loop to calculate the shapley values for all respondents, but this will take me days to calculate for my entire datafile.

```
for(i in c(1:nrow(data_test)))
{
ive_rf <- shap(exp_rf,new_observation=data_test[i,-1])
shapruns<-cbind(shapruns,ive_rf[,"_attribution_"])
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any luck?  The best approach I've found is writing a function to explain one record and using the furrr package to enable parallel processing to use the function to explain many records.  Admittedly, this isn't an ideal approach either.

Answer (score 0):

I recently published two R packages that are optimized for this kind of tasks: "kernelshap" (calculate SHAP values fast) and "shapviz" (plot SHAP values from any source). In your case, a working example would be:

```r
library(randomForest)
library(kernelshap)
library(shapviz)

set.seed(1)
fit <- randomForest(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris,)

# Step 1: Calculate Kernel SHAP values
# bg_X is usually a small (50-200 rows) subset of the data
s <- kernelshap(fit, iris[-1], bg_X = iris)

# Step 2: Turn them into a shapviz object
sv <- shapviz(s)

# Step 3: Gain insights...
sv_importance(sv, kind = "bee")
sv_dependence(sv, v = "Petal.Length", color_var = "auto")
```

[image: Summary plot]
[image: Dependence plot]